# Cannot target Label with .Text from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015.  I've only been using it for 3 days now. This issue persists through any project I'm in.

I want to change the text inside of a label.  I make a new WPF project, drop a label on the form, give the label a name, and make sure it has an "x:" before it in my XAML code.  Intellisense doesn't find "lblTest" when I start typing, and if I type "lblTest.Text", I get this:

'Label' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below are the namespaces I've imported into my project.  I can post my code, but in my example, I just created a blank WPF application, dropped a label on it, and tried to find it.  I really appreciate your time reading this!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

Comment: Try `lblTest.Content` and see if you can update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of WPF controls use different property names from WinForms

In WPF Label uses [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: I love you!  The correct feature I was looking for was lblTest.Content = "Sample";

Comment: I'm happy to help :D